# How to display a message inside an empty div when a component doesn't render in it?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a div inside which I'm rendering dynamic card components(SearchRes):

```
<div className="search-res">
            {games.filter(game => (game.background_image !== null)&&(game.ratings_count>38)).map(game=>
            <SearchRes
            key={game.name} 
            title={game.name} 
            rating={game.metacritic===null?<MdGamepad/>:game.metacritic} 
            genre={game.genres.map(genre=>genre.name+" ")} 
            imglnk={(game.background_image===null)?"":game.background_image}
            gameid={game.id}
            slug={game.slug}
            plat={game.parent_platforms}
            />
            )}
 </div>
```

When the cards don't render (when they don't pass the filter conditions), I get a blank space. I want to display something like `no results found` when such thing happens, how can I implement this?
Currently I'm using CSS to implement it:

```
.search-res:empty::before {
content: "No data";}
```

but clearly this is not viable as the message is visible when the search is not even initiated:
[image: message displayed when search isn't even initiated]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to conditionally render a "No Data" fallback only *after* you've fetched data and there is nothing to render.

1. Add a loading state and conditionally render a loading indicator.
2. Filter the `games` and in the render check that there is an array length (i.e. something to map), and conditionally render the array or the fallback text if there is a current search term.

Code

```
const [searchLoaded, setSearchLoaded] = React.useState(false);

// in search handler
// toggle searchLoaded false when initiating a search
// toggle searchLoaded true when search completes

const results = games.filter(
  game => game.background_image !== null && game.ratings_count > 38
);

<div className="search-res">
  {results.length
    ? results.map(game => (
      <SearchRes
        key={game.name} 
        title={game.name} 
        rating={game.metacritic === null ? <MdGamepad/> : game.metacritic} 
        genre={game.genres.map(({ name }) => name).join(" ")} 
        imglnk={game.background_image === null ? "" : game.background_image}
        gameid={game.id}
        slug={game.slug}
        plat={game.parent_platforms}
      />
    ))
    : searchLoaded && "No Data"
  }
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and initially when the search is not initiated, 'No data' doesn't appear, which is good, but as soon as I start writing in the search bar, 'no data' appears.. how can I make it appear only after I fire my search query

Comment: @DooMGuy096 Ah, right.... I guess I can revert back some of my original answer. You can use some additional "searchComplete" state to indicate a search if finished and you have results to display. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to filter the array first, based on the conditions and then check if the array has length i.e. `arr.length !== 0` and if that is the case, then map the results of the array to the `card component`. And if not then show the message that no data found. You would have to use `if/else` or `ternary operator`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a filter only for conditioning then there is no need for a filter instead you can use conditional rendering like this:

```js
<div className="search-res">
            {games.map(game=>
            {(game.background_image !== null && game.ratings_count>38) ?
            <SearchRes
            key={game.name} 
            title={game.name} 
            rating={game.metacritic===null?<MdGamepad/>:game.metacritic} 
            genre={game.genres.map(genre=>genre.name+" ")} 
            imglnk={(game.background_image===null)?"":game.background_image}
            gameid={game.id}
            slug={game.slug}
            plat={game.parent_platforms}
            /> : "NO RESULTS FOUND"}
            )}
 </div>
```

Comment: This would potentially render a `"NO RESULTS FOUND"` for each element that doesn't meet the filtering condition, probably not quite what OP is looking for.